# Manipulate not moving when combining with ListPlot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying to plot an interactive graph of the geometry about grid-transformation of Lorentz transformation by varying the velocity `v`. I was successful to draw the stationary graph, but the animation didn't move, and it was freezed at the initial condition v=0.7. If I removed the initial condition, the graph will have no lines.

How can I get it fixed? Many thanks!

```
v=0.7
\[Alpha]=Sqrt[1-v^2]
L={{1/\[Alpha],-v/\[Alpha]},{-v/\[Alpha],1/\[Alpha]}}
f[T_: List,x_: List]:=T.x
myinput=DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Union[Table[{i,j},{i,0,3,1},{j,0,5,.01}],Table[{i,j},{i,0,3,.011},{j,0,5,1}]],1];
ListPlot[myinput]
ListPlot[f[L,#]&/@myinput]
Manipulate[ListPlot[f[L,#]&/@myinput],{v,0,1}]
```

Comment: use `L[v_] := {{1/\[Alpha], -v/\[Alpha]}, {-v/\[Alpha], 1/\[Alpha]}` and `Manipulate[ListPlot[f[L[v], #] & /@ myinput], {v, 0, 1}]` ?

Comment: Thanks. I just tried, but then the grid/lines will disappear. Even for the stationary plot, there will be no grid.

Comment: you need to remove the old definition of `L`; either restart mathematica or by `ClearAll[L]; 
L[v_] := {{1/\[Alpha], -v/\[Alpha]}, {-v/\[Alpha], 1/\[Alpha]}}`

Comment: Thanks! Finally got it solved. changed `\[Alpha]` to `\[Alpha][v_]` as well